# WP_Query with page_ids in arguments without a result

Tags: wp-query, database, mysql, array

I want to get some pages with `WP_Query`:

```
  $resume_args = array();

  $resume_args['post_type'] = 'resume';
  $resume_args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
  //$resume_args['page_id'] = array(9046, 9346); //No results!
  $resume_args['page_id'] = 9046; //Works fine

  $resume_args['s'] = 'gassi gehen';

  $resumes = new WP_Query($resume_args);
```

But if I use for `['page_id']` an array I don't get any results.

If I only use one page_id it works everything fine.

Maybe someone could help me with my problem?

It isn't possible to use an array for my arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I have to use `['post__in']`

```
  $resume_args = array();

  $resume_args['post_type'] = 'resume';
  $resume_args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
  $resume_args['post__in'] = array(9046, 9346); //works!

  $resume_args['s'] = 'gassi gehen';

  $resumes = new WP_Query($resume_args);
```